# how to customize my own commands in geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, javascript

How to customize my own commands in geth console?

We know that in geth console, we can type eth.accounts and other commands.
I found that there is a  JavaScript parser/interpreter named Otto which does this, But how to add a new command such as eth.mycommand in geth console?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify source code to achieve, creating a local private chain.

1. Install [go](https://golang.org/doc/install)
2. Clone `go-ethereum` project by `git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git`
3. Rebuild all commands by `make all`, for instance `geth`
4. Test whether everything is ok. `./build/bin/geth --datadir=./dev/data0 --networkid 2  console`. At first you should create directory `./dev/data0` to save chain data. If Ok, now you have entered geth console.

Now, we modify the source code. when `geth` starting, a thread will be created to interact with console by [Interactive](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/console/console.go#L293) method, and last `console.Evaluate()` will deal with input command. So you can implement your logic in here. Now we define a `eth.custom(params)` command to show say-hello. Modify source code as follows:

```
// Evaluate executes code and pretty prints the result to the specified output
// stream.
func (c *Console) Evaluate(statement string) error {
    //fmt.Println(isCustomCommand(statement))
    if (isCustomCommand(statement)) {//custom command,return
        result := "Hello " + statement[strings.Index(statement,"\"")+1:len(statement)-3]
        log.Info(result)
        return nil
    }
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(c.printer, "[native] error: %v\n", r)
        }
    }()
    return c.jsre.Evaluate(statement, c.printer)
}

//our custom is eth.custom(param)
func isCustomCommand(input string) bool{
    return strings.HasPrefix(input,"eth.custom")
}
```

If you input `eth.custom("BinBin")`, it shows `Hello BinBin` on terminal. Now execute

`make all`

command to rebuild, and then execute command to enter console:

```
./build/bin/geth --datadir=./dev/data0 --networkid 2  console
```

Now, we start test, input command as follows:

```
eth.custom("BinBin")
```

and the result is

[image]

perfect!
Hope it helps~

Answer (score 0):

Geth does provide the parameters `--jspath`, `--preload` and `--exec` that can be used to customize the console.

Also there is https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-console which you can use to create your own console.

Comment: thank you , I just want to customize new command such as admin.sayHello,how to modify the source to achieve the goal?

Comment: From the console you can do `admin.sayHello = function (who) { console.log('Hello ' + who); }`. Now you can do from the console `admin.sayHello('World!')` and it will hecho "Hello World!".

Comment: Maybe it is useful, but I want to create some complicated command which can't be achieved by assembling  existing commands.