# How to develop a new module in go-ethereum like eth, admin, etc

Tags: go-ethereum

For instance, the module is named `"mymodule"`.
It can be used in geth console and web3 like `mymodule.funcA()`,`web3.mymodule.funcA()`,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`web3` is a JavaScript object.

You can add new functions like

```
web3.mymodule = {};
web3.mymodule.funcA = function() { /* Code goes here */ };
```

Not sure if you can import custom JavaScript files in the geth console. However you can achieve the same result by just running the javascript code in .js using `node` command as you would copy paste it to geth console.

Comment: I read this post [customize-my-own-geth-command](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18378/how-to-customize-my-own-commands-in-geth-console/24735#24735), but still don't know how the geth console parses commands(for instance "eth.accounts, eth.getBalance("addr")",etc.) and call different build-in modules, which should be written by both go and js. is here some execution framework?